# OS X: always run app with root privileges

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm currently developing an application which needs root privileges for several operations (e.g. deleting system log files, etc.). One solution would be to implement a privileged helper tool which will be launched automatically by launchd. This way the user has to type in an administrator password every time such operation shall be executed (or every time the helper needs to be installed).

Now I wonder if it is possible to create an installer package which will install the application with root privileges so the user types in the administrator credentials just once (during the installation process) and every time the application gets started it is being launched with root permissions (without prompting for admin credentials).

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you use a privileged helper tool, the user may have to authenticate when it is first run, in order for the helper tool to be associated with launchd, but I don't think they'd need to do it every time, especially if you're using an XPC helper: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/bpsystemstartup/chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way to do this on Unix systems is to use [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). Basically, you change the owner of your program to be `root`, and set the "set user or group ID on execution" bit (`s`):

```
$ chown root:root myprogram
$ chmod u+s myprogram
```

Any time a user then executes your program, it will run as root.

Note, though, that **there are very good reasons for prompting for admin credentials**.
Using this mechanism (or doing what you're trying to do, in general), can very easily lead to **very dangerous  security holes** like privilege escalation. Any executable you use `setuid` on should be thoroughly audited by somone familiar with the process, otherwise attackers **will** root all machines your program is installed on.

Comment: You're talking about code injection which would cause 3rd party (hacker) code to be executed (by my application) with root privileges?

Comment: @TheGoonie see [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation). Besides the usual considerations when running as `root` (such as code injection by buffer overflow, for example), you can be the target of a lot of other attacks dealing with the execution environment, such as shell injection

Comment: I see. I think, I will dig further into the privileged helper tools, then. Thanks, goncalopp.

Comment: Hmm... I tried to set the bit and regarding to the permissions information from the terminal the owner is now "root". But when I execute the application the activity monitor still shows me as the executing user (result: the app does not have root permissions).

Comment: @TheGoonie are you sure? try the following: see if you have a `whoami` binary, drop to a root shell, copy `whoami` somewhere, and set the sticky bit, then try to run it as a normal user. [Here's a link showing you how to do it](http://pastebin.com/ETk0vmUu)

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I tried the steps mentioned on the page you've linked to and `whoami` tells me to be "root". The permissions of `whoami` and my app are the same: `rwsr-sr-x`. When I execute my app the Activity Monitor tells me that myself is running the app (not root). I wonder what might be wrong there...

Comment: Small update: Even if I call my app from within a root shell the Activity Monitor shows me as the running user (not root).

Comment: @TheGoonie Are you sure the *owner* of your application is root? Maybe you're `setuid`ing the app to your own user?

Comment: The line `ls` shows is this: `drwsr-sr-x   3 root  staff    102 25 Nov 15:24 PkgInstalledApp.app` So, yes, root is the user of this application.

Comment: I misunderstood what you meant by "app". As I mentioned, `setuid` works *on programs*. I don't know much about OS X, but my guess is that your `PkgInstalledApp.app` [is really a directory](http://answers.bitrock.com/questions/269/how-to-run-app-applications-on-mac-os-x). You need to `setuid` *the actual binary* that runs

Comment: Yes, you're right. In fact on OS X "apps" are directories which contain the real (binary) program. I tried `setuid` on that binary but that results in an app which cannot be started anymore (error message `The application with bundle ID xyz is running setugid(), which is not allowed.`). It seems like it is not possible to run an "app" this way. At least this clarifies the situation. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TheGoonie Apparently [Apple broke `setuid`](https://superuser.com/questions/569513/how-to-run-php-script-via-web-server-as-different-user-under-mac-os-x) recently, and there's no way to do this on newer OS X